# map of map initialization

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, std, stdmap

I am trying to initialize a map of map but I am unsure what mistake I am doing. Below is the sample code.

```
static  std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string,std::string>>  _ScalingMapVolume ={
    {"AA",{"busy_timeout","test"}},
    {"BB",{"cache_size","10000"}}
};
```

The error I am getting is;

> error: no match for call to ‘(std::_Select1st<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> > >) (const char&)’

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{"busy_timeout","test"}` is not the value of a map, but a pair. You need `{{"busy_timeout","test"}}`.

Your code should look like this:

```
static  std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::string>>  _ScalingMapVolume = {
   {"AA", {{"busy_timeout", "test"}}},
   {"BB", {{"cache_size", "10000"}}}
};
```

Comment: I am trying to access the value by _ScalingMapVolume["AA"]["busy_timeout"] but I am not getting "test" instead a 0. Could you please help me out?

Answer (score 1):

```
init = {{"AA", {"busy_timeout", "test"}}, ...}
```

You are missing one set of braces, since the `value_type` of the map is `std::pair<const std::string, std::map<std::string, std::string>>`. The `value_type` of the `mapped_type` is
`std::pair<const std::string, std::string>`. So you need to use it that way.